# Cant get NSDate from textfield

Tags: ios, uitextfield, nsdate

how to get `NSDate` from 
    `uitextfiedl.text`.

I am assiginig

```
self.textfield.text = [NSDate Date];
```

After changing datepicker's value 
    `self.textfield.text` gets changed

so now I want to get that change date from textfield.text

so I am doing

```
NSDate *tempdate = [dateFormat dateFromString:self.textfield.text];
```

but it is printing `2013-01-04.`

So please help me

Comment: `self.textfield.text = [NSDate Date];` I'm pretty sure that `text` is an `NSString` and not an `NSDate`.

Comment: I want to get changed date from textfield.text

Comment: self.textField.text=[NSDate Date] will crash,you haven't mentioned as what exactly is that you want? if you want the date with time then you need to change the dateformatter accordingly.

Answer (score -1):

Try like this..

```
self.textfield.text=[dateFormat StringfromDate: [NSDate Date]];
```

Comment: It's `stringFromDate:`, not `StringfromDate:`.

Comment: @rmaddy, i not copy & paste the code, just giving the idea & xcode will automatically detect it. and for this silly mistake why are you giving the down-vote. Inspire the people to solve others problem.

Comment: Is this helpful to you??

Comment: Its better to solve the question instead of finding silly mistakes.We shouldn't encourage this thing on stack overflow.

Comment: @iPhoneDev, yes i agree with you.

Comment: @iPhoneDev It's better to post answers that work. New devs will simply copy code from the answer and then complain that it doesn't compile or work. Attention to detail is being helpful.